# Export sqlite results to a file

Tags: android

I came across a few questions/answers on SO that deal with exporting a database/table to a txt file. Almost, every solution makes use of Java I/O. I was wondering if anyone has had any success with native sqlite commands. Following is my code and it isn't working. I would really appreciate if anyone has any ideas to get this working.

```
String OutputFile=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+output + ".txt";
databaseHelper.getDatabase().beginTransaction();
databaseHelper.getDatabase().execSQL(".mode list");
databaseHelper.getDatabase().execSQL(".separator |");
databaseHelper.getDatabase().execSQL(".output " + OutputFile);
databaseHelper.getDatabase().execSQL("select * from "+ TABLE_NAME);
databaseHelper.getDatabase().execSQL(".exit");
databaseHelper.getDatabase().endTransaction();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands prefixed with . aren't SQL; they're implemented by the sqlite3 shell. However, if you really want to use this approach, you might be able to call the sqlite3 binary from an Android app. See this [example of how to do this in regular J2SE](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016) for inspiration.

Out of curiosity, why do you want to export to text? sqlite3 binaries are available on many platforms; exporting a database then using desktop tools might make more sense.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to provide the functionality of emailing a table contents to oneself in my Android app. That is the reason I want to export the table to a txt file.

Answer (score 2):

Aren't those command line shell commands not SQL statements? Don't confuse what you can do in a shell (like adb/sqlite3) with SQL statements that you use in the database client framework within your application.

Short answer, I think you have to use Java I/O if you want to export out of the sqlite database into a text file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I now understand that shell commands will not be interpreted in an SQL session.